# Attempting to create a rudimentary calculator with C++; Getting a high amount of compilation errors

Tags: c++

I am incredibly new to programming and this is my first attempting at doing anything. I believe I had declared everything properly as well as the if statements, however I get multiple compilation errors that do not make any sense, as I cannot parse what they are trying to say is wrong with the code. I am incredibly confused and I want to learn what I am doing wrong.

Here is a list:

```
1. main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:28:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘answer’
     cin >> string answer;
                   ^
2. main.cpp:30:19: error: ‘add’ was not declared in this scope
     if (answer == add)
                   ^
3. main.cpp:31:13: error: redeclaration of ‘int add’
     int add(answer1,answer2);
             ^
4. main.cpp:30:19: note: ‘add’ previously declared here
     if (answer == add)
                   ^
5. main.cpp:31:13: error: ‘answer1’ was not declared in this scope
     int add(answer1,answer2);
             ^
6. main.cpp:31:21: error: ‘answer2’ was not declared in this scope
     int add(answer1,answer2);
                     ^
7. main.cpp:31:28: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
     int add(answer1,answer2);
                            ^
8. main.cpp:33:5: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
     else if (answer == subtract)
     ^
9. main.cpp:33:24: error: ‘subtract’ was not declared in this scope
     else if (answer == subtract)
                        ^
10. main.cpp:34:18: error: redeclaration of ‘int subtract’
     int subtract(answer1,answer2);
                  ^
11. main.cpp:33:24: note: ‘subtract’ previously declared here
     else if (answer == subtract)
                        ^
12. main.cpp:34:18: error: ‘answer1’ was not declared in this scope
     int subtract(answer1,answer2);
                  ^
13. main.cpp:34:26: error: ‘answer2’ was not declared in this scope
     int subtract(answer1,answer2);
                          ^
14. main.cpp:34:33: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
     int subtract(answer1,answer2);
                                 ^
15. main.cpp:36:5: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
     else if (answer == multiply)
     ^
16. main.cpp:36:24: error: ‘multiply’ was not declared in this scope
     else if (answer == multiply)
                        ^
17. main.cpp:37:18: error: redeclaration of ‘int multiply’
     int multiply(answer1,answer2);
                  ^
18. main.cpp:36:24: note: ‘multiply’ previously declared here
     else if (answer == multiply)
                        ^
19. main.cpp:37:18: error: ‘answer1’ was not declared in this scope
     int multiply(answer1,answer2);
                  ^
20. main.cpp:37:26: error: ‘answer2’ was not declared in this scope
     int multiply(answer1,answer2);
                          ^
21. main.cpp:37:33: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
     int multiply(answer1,answer2);
                                 ^
22. main.cpp:39:5: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
     else if (answer == divide)
     ^
23. main.cpp:39:24: error: ‘divide’ was not declared in this scope
     else if (answer == divide)
                        ^
24. main.cpp:40:16: error: redeclaration of ‘int divide’
     int divide(answer1,answer2);
                ^
25. main.cpp:39:24: note: ‘divide’ previously declared here
     else if (answer == divide)
                        ^
26. main.cpp:40:16: error: ‘answer1’ was not declared in this scope
     int divide(answer1,answer2);
                ^
27. main.cpp:40:24: error: ‘answer2’ was not declared in this scope
     int divide(answer1,answer2);
                        ^
28. main.cpp:40:31: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
     int divide(answer1,answer2);
                               ^
29. main.cpp:42:5: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
     else if
     ^
30. main.cpp:43:5: error: expected ‘(’ before ‘cout’
     cout << "Invalid Option!";
     ^
31. main.cpp: At global scope:

32. main.cpp:50:14: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
 int subtract(a,b);
              ^
33. main.cpp:50:16: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
 int subtract(a,b);
                ^
34. main.cpp:50:17: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 int subtract(a,b);
                 ^
35. main.cpp:51:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
36. main.cpp:56:14: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
 int multiply(a,b);
              ^
37. main.cpp:56:16: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
 int multiply(a,b);
                ^
38. main.cpp:56:17: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 int multiply(a,b);
                 ^
39. main.cpp:57:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
40. main.cpp:62:9: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
 int add(a,b);
         ^
41. main.cpp:62:11: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
 int add(a,b);
           ^
42. main.cpp:62:12: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 int add(a,b);
            ^
43. main.cpp:63:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
44. main.cpp:68:12: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
 int divide(a,b);
            ^
45. main.cpp:68:14: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
 int divide(a,b);
              ^
46. main.cpp:68:15: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
 int divide(a,b);
               ^
47. main.cpp:69:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int number1;
int number2;
string answer;
int result;
int a;
int b;


cout << "Enter first number" << endl;
cin >> number1;
cout << "Enter second number" << endl;
cin >> number2;
cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl << "Options: Add, substract, 
multiply, divide" << endl;
cin >> string answer;

if (answer == add)
int add(answer1,answer2);
 cout << result;
else if (answer == subtract)
int subtract(answer1,answer2);
 cout << result;
else if (answer == multiply)
int multiply(answer1,answer2);
 cout << result;
else if (answer == divide)
int divide(answer1,answer2);
cout << result;
else if
cout << "Invalid Option!";
return 0;

}



int subtract(a,b);
{
 result = a-b;
 return result;   
}

int multiply(a,b);
{
    cout << a*b;
}

int add(a,b);
{
cout << a+b;
}

int divide(a,b);
{
    cout << a/b;
 }
```

Comment: There is a **lot** wrong here. Honestly I'd suggest scrapping this and rewriting from the beginning. After every 2-5 lines (whenever you finish an if or some output or a function), compile and run and make sure things are happening the way you expect. When you write up 50+ lines all at once and just hope everything will compile and work at this programming level, you're going to be spending a **lot** of time scrolling through comipler errors. And once you've dealt with those, things will still probably be broken with your logic.

Comment: Good to know, will do. Thanks.

Comment: `(answer == add)` : a key problem is that `add` needs to be in quotes; otherwise, the compiler interprets it as an object (variable, function, whatever). Hence: `error: ‘add’ was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: Ohh, I see. That makes sense.

Comment: You have a ton of global variables that you don't need which will easily introduce bugs into your code. Your functions promise to return `int` but don't which is bad, and you have a ton of incorrect semicolons and other syntactic problems. I would suggest you put this code aside, go ready and study thoroughly a [good C++ book for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and then restart this project from scratch, making only incremental changes and compiling and testing often

Comment: C++ is not a language to learn by trial and error. C++ has a dark side called Undefined Behaviour which means that serious bugs in your code don't always give compiler errors and throw exceptions. Learn by example and by reading documention.

Answer (score 2):

Don't give up! Try starting from the beginning. Move slowly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

/*
This is regarded as bad practice...
From Python's `import this`:
   Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
*/
using namespace std;

// Define your function
int add(int a, int b);

int main()
{

    int number1, number2, result;
    string answer;

    cout << "Enter first number" << endl;
    cin >> number1;
    cout << "Enter second number" << endl;
    cin >> number2;
    cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl << "Options: Add, substract, multiply, divide" << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    cout << "You chose: " << answer << endl;

    // Can this handle lowercase "add"? If not, how do you fix it?
    if (answer == "Add") {
        result = add(number1,number2);
        cout << number1 << " + " << number2 << " = " << result << endl;
    }
    // What about divide, multiply, etc.?
    // That's an exercise left to the reader ;)

}

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

This produces:

```
Enter first number
12

Enter second number
12

What would you like to do?
Options: Add, substract, multiply, divide
Add

You chose: Add
12 + 12 = 24
```

Comment: Let me know if there's anything confusing about this code compared to yours and I'll write up a response.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong, not using result and not working functions correctly. I managed to fix everything and do everything the program was intended to do ^_^

Comment: Awesome, great job! :) Keep at it! ..and make sure to upvote the answers of everyone that helped ;)

Comment: Bonus challenge: consider the edge cases. What if someone passes in `"abcd"` instead of a number into `result1`? What will happen then? What if someone writes `"AdD"` or `"aDD"` or `"ADD"` instead of `"add"`? Extra *extra* bonus challenge: can you write a program that doesn't ask for the operation, but instead parses it automatically? i.e. input: `5 / 4 -> divide(5,4)`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `cin >> string answer;` use `cin >> answer;`. You've a;ready got answer declared, so declaring it here is not necessary (and actually not legal). Other than that your add, subtract, multiply and divide functions are declared too soon. Add declarations or move those function definitions before main. You've got extra ; signs after between function declaration and it's body and you're missing types of functions arguments

```
int subtract(a,b); // delete ; here and add int (or better float) before a and b
{
 result = a-b; // you need to declare result, add type before this line (int or float, float would be better
 return result;   
}
```

Also number1 and number2 should be at least floats (or doubles), otherwise you're gonna have a bad time with division operations.

Hit me up if you've got more questions about it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Also I've noticed you don't have returns in most of your functions. If you're saying 'int somefunctionname()' you have to have return somewhere. Also you don't need type name before calling your function, but you should catch the result ('result = add(number1, number2)' instead of int add(number1,number2)'). If you want to have more than one line of code executed conditionally you need to surround them with braces. Last if in ie-else ladder is also not correct.

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> string answer;` doesn't make sense. `string answer` is not an expression, so you can't use it as the right-hand operand of the `>>` operator.

You probably meant `cin >> answer;` because `string answer;` was already declared earlier in the function.

Also, you're missing `#include <string>`.

(This answer only covers the first error. I usually only look at the first error message, fix the code, then compile again. In your case there seems to be a lot more wrong with the code. Sorry.)

Comment: Don't forget his returns (or lack thereof) in the functions...and the multiline string...and the missing condition in the last `else if`...and the semicolons after all the function headers in the implementations....and all of the if conditions trying to use variables instead of string literals...I don't think it's even worth trying to fix this.

Comment: @scohe001 The multiline string is probably a copy/paste error and not in the original code. The compiler doesn't seem to complain about it.

Comment: Fair enough. Swap "and the multiline string..." for "and the way he's trying to call his functions from main..." then :p honestly there's something else that jumps out at me every time I look at it

Comment: I won't try to fix it then. I'm sorry.

Comment: @scohe001 Here's a fun one: "substract" is misspelled, but only in the prompt. It's correct in the actual logic. :-)

Comment: @Pseudoscorpion don't be sorry, everyone's code looks terribad when they first start out! I'm sure you'll look back in as soon as a few weeks and be able to find almost all of your mistakes. The trick is limiting the errors you have to deal with to a minimum by only writing a little at a time before compiling and checking it. I'm sure you'll get better--it just takes practice!!